# C# Why create multiple references to a single object?

Tags: c#, reference

**Situation:** I recently came across an article where an employer was asking entry-level candidates to solve a complex reference problem (not shown), as well as questions pertaining to the stack and managed heap. I have devoted a bit of time to learning these concepts for personal understanding, but was not aware that these are considered 'entry-level' knowledge. Being a CIS major apposed to CS (huge difference I know) these concepts are not taught.

**Question** Why would a developer assign an object reference to another reference? More succinctly, why would a developer ever flip flop dozens of references around as described in interview scenarios? Is this simply a matter of testing subject matter comprehension, or is this 'reference flip-flopping' a practice used in "everyday" development?

```
using System;

namespace QuickConsoleTesting
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main()
     {
         //Instantiate two new Person objects on the heap
         Person person1 = new Person() { Name = "Jim" };
         Person person2 = new Person() { Name = "Todd" };
         Person person3 = person1;
         Person person4 = new Person() { Name = "Julie" };

         //Flip-flop reference variables
         person4 = person2;
         person1 = person3;

         //Display results
         Console.WriteLine(person1.Name);
         Console.WriteLine(person2.Name);
         Console.WriteLine(person3.Name);
         Console.WriteLine(person4.Name);

        /* ======================================
         * Results displayed: Jim, Todd, Jim, Todd
         * ===================================== */

        //Hold console window
        Console.Read();

      }//END OF MAIN
    }//END OF PROGRAM

    class Person
    {
       private string name = "";

       public string Name
       {
          get { return name; }
          set { name = value; }
       }
    }//END OF PERSON

 }//END OF NAMESPACE
```

Comment: What? System.Object does not have a property called "Name". your code doesn't compile.

Comment: `is this 'must-have' knowledge used in "everyday" development?` Yes, it is.

Comment: What if you had a list of `Person`s, and wanted to find the oldest person? That would require changing references quite a few times. There are many examples. of course.

Comment: object1 would not be garbage collected

Comment: Sorry, I just created the code block as example for general purposes. I'll edit it to compile.

Comment: Why is the output not `Jim` `Jim`?

Comment: @Kobi Either way it won't compile as not enough code as given.  That said, if you make an object and call it `Object` I'm liable to smack you.

Comment: @Kobi it would be silly for anyone to create a custom class called `Object` because it would cause ambiguity everywhere. `Using System;`. Anyone?

Comment: now you guys could stop arguing..

Comment: @Kobi Why does everyone assume that when you give someone a hard time for giving you a hard time you don't realize they're joking?  I was just giving you a hard time for giving us a hard time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These sort of questions are there to test if a candidate understands the difference between a reference variable and a value variable. The supplied scenario (as is) will almost never happen in Real World (tm) code. But, confusion resulting in *not* understanding why this code snippet does what it does can and does result in a lot of bugs, especially when there are various functions working on the same data.

Comment: A value type would be exactly the same here. It would be different with another line after the assignment - `object1.Name = "Bob";`

Comment: @Kobi: Indeed, candidates should be tested to ensure they understand value types as well as reference types. I find absurd the notion that the semantics of exposed-field value types are "too confusing" to justify their use, given that such types can allow code that is much clearer and more maintainable than any plausible alternative using other types. To be sure, structs with read-write properties used to be problematic, but fields didn't have such problems and in most cases offered clearer semantics anyway (is there any good reason why `Point` shouldn't expose fields `X` and `Y`?)

Comment: I have to agree with this answer. If the whole point of the interview question is to test someones knowledge of value/reference types, than there must be better ways of doing it than the example scenario.

Answer (score 2):

imagine a class

```
class Person
{
pubic string Name;
}
```

---

With pass by value which is default

```
Person p=new Person();
//p contains the address of the newly allocated person
change(p);
//p is passed by value so the address within p would get copied into p1 which is a method parameter of change method

public void change(Person p1)
//p1 and p are separate variables containing address of person object
{
    p1.Name="SO";
    //changes name of p1 and p
    p1=null;
    //this makes p1 null not p since p and p1 are separate copies pointing to person object
}
```

---

With reference

```
change(ref p);
//p is now passed by reference so p1 is p
public void change(ref Person p1)//p1 and p are same
{
    p1.Name="SO";
    p1=null;//this makes p and p1 null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you're asking, there are many reasons a developer might store the same reference in multiple variables, but that all depends on the code. Remember there is still only one place that the object lives on in the heap, but could have many references to it (and thats where Managed Garbage Collector comes in to clean up objects no longer referenced)

Obviously your example is simply bad code. These types of questions are akin to the C++ pointer questions. C# as a manged language has tried to stay away from pointers, but it is still important to understand the differences between value types and reference types. This is mostly what these questions are designed for.